# Dynamics 365: Change the default view to a custom search

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Is there a way to change the default list page when you click on a entity form to a custom search page? Something like google ( a text box with a search button) to return the results of the list base on the search criteria?

for example,

from this:

[image]

to a search page.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you can't. This page is not customizable. But the dashboards are. You can make a custom dashbard with a single iframe and it can be your default page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you cannot modify the design of this list page. Dashboard & custom html webresource/iframe is fine.

But I recommend you to customize this list page itself to look like what you want, atleast close to similar CRM UX. First deactivate all the views for that particular entity except Active & Quick find. Rename the system view “Active Details” into “Search” & modify the filter condition to include something like `createdon = tomorrow`. Hence the grid will be empty, you got search box on right to start with. When user search, Quick find view resultset will be rendered in grid.